# Publishing an app, problems with "Required device features"

Tags: android, google-play

I've published my app on the Market, but it somehow auto-detected several features that it thinks are required. One of those features is "android.hardware.telephony", and because this is now a required feature, my app can't be installed on wifi-only tablets.

I don't have any "uses-feature" declarations in the manifest file, but my app does have the capability to make calls. I guess that Google is requiring "android.hardware.telephony" because of this functionality. However, this functionality is just a value-added feature. It is by no means required for the core functionality of the app.

I don't want to completely remove the telephony functionality because there are way more users with phone devices vs. wifi-only devices. I also don't want to create and maintain another version of the app for wifi-only devices. Is there any way for me to mark telephony as an optional feature, so that both types of devices can use my app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html .

In your case add
         <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
         android:required="false" />
to your manifest.